# Where does GCC look for its internal executables?

Tags: osx, gcc

I have installed GCC to a custom prefix.  When it is invoked, it complains that it cannot find some of its internal binaries.

My computer's "official" GCC keeps them here:

```
/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1
```

This directory is not present in `PATH`.

`make install` created a similar hierarchy under my prefix, and the appropriate files were installed there.  I could add it to `PATH`, but this was apparently not necessary for the official GCC to run.  I would like to avoid cluttering `PATH` if I can.

I looked for an option to specify this directory in the `configure` script, but found none.  There is also no mention of `libexec` in the GCC manual.

How does the official GCC know where its internal binaries live, and how can I give this information to my trunk build of GCC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask `gcc` where it will look for those binaries: (this works on FC16's gcc-4.6.3 and CentOS 5.3 gcc-4.1.3, so it should work with your 4.2)

`gcc -print-search-dirs`

You can set your search path via `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX` environment variable.